# CMake when FetchContent rabbitmq

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, rabbitmq

I am trying to integrate rabbitmq into one of the modules of my solution in order to switch from mailslots to rabbitmq. The problem is that during the fectcontent, the module "breaks" the links of the other modules. The errors generated are "unresolved external symbols".

```
##########################
# CODE CMAKELISTS
##########################
file(GLOB sources "src/*.cpp" "src/*.c")
file(GLOB headers "inc/*.hpp" "inc/*.h")

project("${MODULE_NAME}${MODULE_TYPE}")

set(OUTPUT_FILE "${MODULE_NAME}${MODULE_TYPE}")
OPTION(BUILD_TESTS "Build the tests" OFF)

MESSAGE(STATUS "Building : ${PROJECT_NAME}...")
if(BUILD_TESTS)
    enable_testing()
    ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(test)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Building : ${PROJECT_NAME} test...")
endif()

################################
# RabbitMQ
################################
SET(ENABLE_SSL_SUPPORT OFF CACHE PATH "Shall RabbitMQ be built with ssl support" FORCE)
include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
    rabbitmq
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.git
    GIT_TAG        v0.10.0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(rabbitmq)
if(NOT rabbitmq_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(rabbitmq)
    add_subdirectory(${rabbitmq_SOURCE_DIR} ${rabbitmq_BINARY_DIR})
endif()

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES( ${sources} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX )
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES( ${headers} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX )
```

Type of error:

LNK2001 external symbol not resolved "struct fsTUN_GlobalSection_t tun" (?tun@@3UfsTUN_GlobalSection_t@@A)  MOD.LIB fsMOD_maxSpeed.obj  1

LNK2019 external symbol not resolved "long __cdecl fsRTS_MaxSpeed(long,struct _iobuf *,long,long,long,long,struct fs_products *,struct fsSEQ_Adaptation *,double,double,double,double,double *,double *,struct rts_mod *)" (?fsRTS_MaxSpeed@@YAJJPEAU_iobuf@@JJJJPEAUfs_products@@PEAUfsSEQ_Adaptation@@NNNNPEAN3PEAUrts_mod@@@Z) referenced in the function "long __cdecl fsMOD_maxSpeed(struct fs_products *,struct fsSEQ_Adaptation *)" (?fsMOD_maxSpeed@@YAJPEAUfs_products@@PEAUfsSEQ_Adaptation@@@Z)  MOD.LIB ..\fsMOD_maxSpeed.obj   1

Comment: Please edit your post to show the actual error output from CMake and/or the compilation process.

Comment: Wrapping CMAKE variables in strings is usually a good idea

Comment: There are two languages in your linker output (looks like french and english). Do you compile with different toolchains? The error saying that fsTUN_GlobalSection_t and fsMOD_maxSpeed functions are missing. I don't think these are rabbitmq functions.

Comment: i dont have error with rabbitmq function, my problem is when i add rabbitmq in my project, my solution does not compile and I get the above errors